# Error in enumarated value

Tags: sql

when i am trying to update my table  it shows me error:

MyQuery :

```
update tableName set mytype="abcd" where id="a1245"
```

error : The enumerated value "abcd" may not be used in the element "Account Type" in this request.".

info: mytype is varchar

any idea?

Comment: Could you post your table structure?

Comment: and also triggers you may have on this table.

Comment: What dbase system are you using? MsSql or Mysql? Try to add more information to the question. Can you put a create statement from the table so we can see its definition?

Comment: Sounds to me that value "abcd" is not a valid enumeration value from the table definition.

Comment: Thanks friend for commenting here..  i got solution by alter my table and add enum value >>   ALTER TABLE `tableName` CHANGE `mytype` `mytype`
ENUM('ranki','zedg', 'abcd') CHARACTER SET utf8
COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;

Answer (score -1):

use single instead of double quotes

```
update tableName set mytype='abcd' where id='a1245'
```